# Sails Model find where "childAttributs"

Tags: sails.js, waterline, model-associations

I have 3 models User, Scene, Player.

It is possible to have something like :

```
Player.find({"scene.user" : "someID", name : {'like' : '%' + key + '%'}}).populate("scene").exec(function(err, data)
{
    ....
});
```

Rules associations are : 
User as many scene Scene
Scene has one User
Scene has many Player
Player has one Scene

I know I can make it with filter after request like this (below) but want to know if sails can make it as one request.

Workaround :

```
Scene.find({user : userID}).populate("players", {Name : {'like' : '%' + key + '%'}}).then(function (elements)
    {
      var listPlayerOfCurrentUser = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
      {
        var scenario            = elements[i];
        listPlayerOfCurrentUser = listPlayerOfCurrentUser.concat(scenario.players);
      }
      if (listPlayerOfCurrentUser.length > 0)
      {
        res.json(listPlayerOfCurrentUser);
      }
      else
      {
        res.status(404).json({error : 'no player found'});
      }
    }).catch(function (error)
    {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({error : 'DB error'});
    });
```